# Win7: change "Device Stage" import to Dropbox import

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, autoplay

As usual, Microsoft fixed for me something that did not needed fixing.

When connecting a few of my cameras, I get Dropbox import, which plays nicely with my backup scheme (esp. since Dropbox automatically provides nice, consistent names for files).

Not so for my Nikon D90 - Windows built-in Import fires up. I tried changing that in Autoplay settings, but to no avail - I can either use DeviceStage import, or take No Action at all.

Does anyone know how to change this? I searched Google and Dropbox forums, but it's like I'm the only one in the world with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it.

In Device Stage, double click on the device.

Change "Import program" to Dropbox.

Click "Change default settings" and set "Import via Dropbox".

Be proud of yourself ;-)